# What's the point of creating a view of a table in a database that has the same info as the table?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I know little to nothing about sql and databases, but I have to work in a codebase that creates db files.

The db file contains a table called `DailyCosts`, and in the code I see that it creates a view using the following sql command:

```
  create view DC as select * from DailyCosts
```

What exactly is the point of creating a view that references the entire table? From my understanding of views, it's usually used to simplify access to a table, e.g., creating a view of a subset of the table and then querying against that view instead of the full table. In this case, it seems pointless?

Also, if it matters, this is done using `sqlite3` in python

Comment: Yeah, this does seem pointless.  I can think of some reasons to do it, but none of them are _good_ reasons.

Comment: @NotAName when you access a view, is it only in read-only mode? i.e., you can't modify the content of the view and have that be reflected in the original db table?

Comment: it provides an abstraction. if it ever needs to change, your app code doesn't have to refer to other tables

Comment: I have created views that while they were only over 1 table, existed to change table and column names to make the new schema backwardly compatible with a legacy system. But abstraction for abstraction's sake doesn't warrant creating a view that "does nothing".

Answer (score 0):

In fact we should never program an application which directly accesses tables, but systematically go through views, what theorists like Franck Edgar Codd (creator of Relational DBMS) or Chris Date (relational theorist) call the "External Model of Data"...

Some explanations:

https://www.programsbuzz.com/article/internal-and-external-data-models

[https://www.umsl.edu/~sauterv/analysis/Fall2010Papers/Gao/](https://www.umsl.edu/%7Esauterv/analysis/Fall2010Papers/Gao/)

If you do not use such a model, the slightest modification to the structure of a table will require considerable effort to modify all the queries that relate to this table in applications. In reality, recoding is so complex and expensive that we often abandon the restructuring in favor of simply adding new columns or new tables while considering the old ones as no longer used. But this has a cost from the DBA's point of view, particularly in terms of backup, resources or maintenance...

Now if you add the external model consisting of views, triggers and procedures and you prohibit applications from directly accessing the tables, it is easy to restructure the tables without any impact on the applications. All you have to do is redefine the views and the application continues to work....

The developers just forgot or we forgot to teach them that a view can be updated (INSERT, UDPATE, DELETE...) in all cases, either directly or indirectly through INSTEAD triggers OF...

This is what Franck Edgar Codd said in his 12 rules for RDBMSs "Rule 6: The view updating rule:"
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codd%27s_12_rules